# Running Selenium test suite with browser minimized

Tags: selenium-rc

As part of our web application deployment I need to do basic smoke test after the deployment.

I am using Selenium RC to run the smoke test automatically at the end of the deployment.

now How can I run the browser minimized (not poping up) while running the test suite.

Below is the command used to run the test suite

java -jar D:\Selenium\RC\selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -htmlSuite *firefox https://abc.com C:\Users\abc\Desktop\testsuite.html results.html -firefoxProfileTemplate C:\Users\331036\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles\imvteil2.selenium

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternate solution that may meet your needs. You can set the position of the WebDriver to be outside of your view. That way, it'll be out of sight while it runs. (It may start at a visible location, but it will only be there for an instant.)

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(-2000, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible, The Browser will pop up , you will have to minimize it manually